# What is the purpose of routes_out dictionary in routes.py of web2py?

Tags: web2py

I understand that routes_in rewrites a url to some other url which web2py understands but i dont understand what routes_out does.

Answer (score 1):

web2py includes a `URL()` function to generate URLs for links, static assets, Ajax requests, etc. The `routes_out` patterns are used by the `URL()` function to generate these outgoing URLs. For example, `URL('default', 'myfunc')` might generate the URL `/myfunc` (rather than `/default/myfunc`) if `routes_out` is specified so as to hide the `default` controller.